# Autocomplete opens in the wrong window

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-coc

When using vim with coc installed, auto-complete is always opening **and characters are being inserted** into the window where the first auto-complete was displayed.

- I have a directory with two files (`main.ts` and `second.ts`)
- I open the first file in vim: `vi main.ts`
- I do any editing which triggers auto-complete (e.g. enter insert mode type 'i', which prompts auto-complete option of `if`, among others)
- I open the `second.ts` file in another window: `:vsplit second.ts`
- In the new window (from now on the *right* window, and the window showing `main.ts` will be the *left* window), I do any editing which triggers auto-complete (e.g. enter insert mode and type 'h')

  - The autocomplete options appear in the *left* window
  - Any subsequent characters are also entered in the *left* window (e.g. if I type "hello", `h` is entered in the *right* window, and `ello` is entered in the *left* window.
- Any characters incorrectly entered in the *left* window, are part of the buffer (e.g. if I save the left window with `:w`, `ello` will be included in the file written to disk), but are not part of the undo history for that buffer (e.g. if after typing "hello", I exit insert mode and `U` to undo, the characters `ello` remain, and the previous edit in that window is undone).

I'm just starting to seriously replace VSCode with vim, so I'm fairly new to the ecosystem and haven't had luck finding others with similar issues with Google searches. I'm not sure which environmental issues are the most important to isolate first for this kind of an issue.

The full list of plugins I have installed is below:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'rust-lang/rust.vim'
call plug#end()
```

The problem continues to happen when I comment out everything except coc.nvim, and goes away if I comment out coc.nvim

Comment: If you remove coc.nvim from the equation, do you have the same problem? If yes, then you should probably open an issue in Vim's issue tracker. If no, then you should use the plugin's official support channels, where you are far more likely to find a solution than here.

Comment: This looks really odd :-| I would be happy to see a short screen cast. I'm using Vim and Coc on several windows (splits) in parallel and I don't experiment that behavior. Did you have it with a very short subset of plugins (e.g. only Coc)?

Comment: @romainl That was helpful, thanks. When I comment out `coc.nvim` from my Plug section of my `.vimrc`, the problem indeed goes away. I'm new enough to vim that I thought a plugin was required to get autocomplete prompts, so it was helpful enough to just try without COC. Stock vim doesn't seem to have the problem, so I'll also go ask in COC specific forums also. Thanks

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I've uploaded a screen recording to S3 here: https://tmp-file-share-2b1a3b35a9683740c5d06b4921016ce2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vim-coc-autocomplete.mp4 (191.1 KB).

In the recording I: open main.ts, start typing `ma`, and then autocomplete `main`, then delete the line. I open a vsplit with second.ts, start typing `hello`, `ESC` to exit insert mode, then undo and redo several times, before `qall!`

Comment: I've now also asked this question on the coc github discussion area (https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/discussions/4578) and will update here if I get a resolution there.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt The full list of my plugins from my vimrc has been added to the question.

It continues to occur even when I comment out fzf and rust and only leave coc.nvim in the Plug section.

Comment: This was resolved in the coc github discussion thread. Apparently there was a similar reported issue that was resolved by upgrading vim to at least patch 961 (9.0.961).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar issue reported in coc ([#4396 Inserting text in a split window causes the cursor to jump to another split](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/4396)) that was resolved by upgrading vim to at least patch 961 (9.0.961).

I updated vim to the latest available patch (9.0.1424), and that resolved my issue.